# iterating problem in json data, iterating same data over and over

Tags: javascript

I have a iteration problem with json data. I send an array to javascript. To use it convert it to json data and pass it to javascript var.

```
<script>
  var estates = <?php echo json_encode($estates);?>;

  function initMap(){
    var options =
        {
            zoom : 6,
            center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
        };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    @foreach ($estates as $est)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
              url: "/pages/{{$est->id}}",
              label: {
                  text: estates.data[0].price,
                  color: "#fff",
              },
              position: {
                  lat: {{$est->lat}},
                  lng: {{$est->lng}}
              }
          });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
       window.location.href = this.url;
     });
  @endforeach
  }
</script>
```

But at this line `estates.data[0].price,` my label is iterate same price over and over. it's because i am giving [0] to it. But if I don't give a number then it doesn't go into `data` and couldn't find the `price`. Is there anyway to iterate json. because now it giving me same price over and over like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znOXj.jpg)

By the way I already tried the iteration below. But this time every each marker label having the ALL prices at once...

```
for(let i = 0; i < estates.data.length; i++){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
          url: "/pages/{{$est->id}}",
          label: {
              text: estates.data[i].price,
              color: "#fff",
          },
          position: {
              lat: {{$est->lat}},
              lng: {{$est->lng}}
          }
      });
}
```

And also I tried this as well:

```
<?php
    $js_array = json_encode($estates);
    echo "var estates = ". $js_array . ";\n";
   ?>;

for(var i = 0; i < estates.data.length; i++){
  var needle = estates.data[i];
  for(var key in needle){
    var obj = needle.price;
    console.log(obj)
  }
}

for(var itr = 0; itr < obj.length; itr++){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
      url: "/pages/{{$est->id}}",
      label: {
          text: obj[itr],
          color: "#fff",
      },
      position: {
          lat: {{$est->lat}},
          lng: {{$est->lng}}
      }
    });
}
```

But still not running properly....

Comment: Maybe it is `$est->price` instead of `estates.data[0].price`? It produces the same data because you specify the constant index to `estates.data` which is `[0]`.

Comment: Oh,  I trid that first :) but   invalid token error pops up. Because javascript can't read the Japanese. So to overcome that problem I use json. @holydragon

Comment: So if this way works for you, try changing 0 to the index of each data in the iteration.

Comment: that's.. not work for me...

Comment: If it's a javascript issue, post actual data, not PHP.  Otherwise, this is off topic (since questions on "*why isn't this code working*" need the actual code in the question). It's either a PHP question because it's invalid PHP or generating syntactically invalid javascript, or it's a javascript question because the values are wrong. Either way, you need to show what the PHP generates.

Comment: I think its iterating over the same value, because you just have always the same index.

Comment: yes, but if I don't give index it doesn't go into data and take the price... @LukasGermerott

Comment: Maybe you have to make a loop to iterate over the array?

Comment: I tried it too, but each labels having the every price at once... Maybe i couldn't iterate well... could you drop an answer for that. @LukasGermerott

Comment: I give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with a little touch.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
      url: "/pages/{{$est->id}}",
      label: {
          text: "{{$est->price}}",
          color: "#fff",
      },
      position: {
          lat: {{$est->lat}},
          lng: {{$est->lng}}
      }
});
```

Price is varchar, so used this loop in quotes "{{$est->price}}" and now need to json.encode also...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to wrap a for loop around it.
I could not test it, because I don't have the PHP code.

```
@foreach ($estates as $est)
for(let i = 0; i < estates.data.length; i++){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
          url: "/pages/{{$est->id}}",
          label: {
              text: estates.data[i]
              color: "#fff",
          },
          position: {
              lat: {{$est->lat}},
              lng: {{$est->lng}}
          }
      });
}

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
   window.location.href = this.url;
 });
```

**Edit:** Or you could try to edit this line `text: {{$est->data}}`

**Edit²**: Just delete the php stuff and only run in javascript? I deleted the php foreach loop and just try to use the javascript object.

```
<script>
  var estates = <?php echo json_encode($estates);?>;

  function initMap(){
    var options =
        {
            zoom : 6,
            center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
        };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    for(let i = 0; i < estates.length; i++){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: 'imgs/marker.png',
              url: "/pages/"+estates[i].id,
              label: {
                  text: estates.data[0].price,
                  color: "#fff",
              },
              position: {
                  lat: estates[i].lat,
                  lng: estates[i].lng
              }
          });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
       window.location.href = this.url;
     });
    }
  }
</script>
```

I hope that helps

Comment: okay, need to add this. `estates.data[i].price` but I said it before with this for loop it's iterating all prices for each marker...

Comment: I put in a second solution, please try that out

Comment: i need php in there for the urls. also i tried it anyway but it doesn't helped... thank you for the afford.

Comment: thank you for the afford but this won't help, i need php for the url->id and also i tried it but it doesn't worked.

Comment: I editet it, could you please try the second solution again? I modified the ID part.

Comment: Okay at this point, I can't help you because I have no working snippet and I cannot debug.

Comment: If you could give me the estates array, that would help I think